# ¿Cómo detectar espacios en blanco?

Tags: batch

Tengo un `.bat` que sirve para cambiar nombres a archivos `.jpg`

El nombre original del archivo es un código numérico de 4 o 5 digitos y después un espacio y una ristra de caracteres alfanuméricos. Tal que:

> `1001 ASDFGJHJS.jpg`

Tengo este codigo que los renombra cogiendo los 5 primeros caracteres.

```
for %%i in ("*.jpg") do (set fname=%%i) & call :rename
goto :eof
:rename
::Cuts off  five chars, then appends .jpg
ren "%fname%" "%fname:~0,5%.jpg"
goto :eof
```

**¿Cómo detecto el espacio para que sean los 4 o 5 primeros dígitos los que coja?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La solución que encontré fue algo simple que no habia probado:

```
IF "%fname:~4,1%"==" " (ren "%fname%" "%fname:~0,4%.jpg") else (ren "%fname%" "%fname:~0,5%.jpg")
```

Con el `IF "%fname:~4,1%"==" "` compruebo el 5nto caracter, si es un espacio en blanco cojo los 4 primeros caracteres, si no es un espacio cojo los 5 primeros